# Overwrite referenced files (in .Files) in a Subchart or insert mariadb initial files from a main chart

Tags: kubernetes, initialization, mariadb, kubernetes-helm

So I have a mariadb subchart. The mariadb charts fills a config map from diffrent init files with:

```
{{ (.Files.Glob "files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*[sh|sql|sql.gz]").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

So is there anyway I can inject the init files ?

Is it possible to overwrite the context of `.Files.Glob` so it access my parent directory ? or is there another recommended way to create initial sql files ?

the maridb subchart is implented like this in the `requirements.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- name: mariadb
  version: 5.x.x
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  condition: mariadb.enabled
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2221

Comment: `the most common method seems to be to change the literal glob path to a variable: .Files.Glob .Values.globals.dashboards` how do i do this ? I tried with the `import-values` statement in `requirment.yaml` but it doesnt work because it cant finde the table "Files"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your mariadb is a subchart managed by third party, `.Files.Glob` refers only to files inside mariadb directory.

If you want to place any startup scripts inside subchart, you have to unarchive it.

Let's say you have **custom-init-scripts** directory with all init scripts in your parent chart.

```
$ ls custom-init-scripts/
init.sh  insert.sql

# download mariadb chart package in charts directory
$ helm dependency update

# unarchive and delete package
$ tar -xvf charts/mariadb-5.*.tgz -C charts && rm charts/mariadb-5.*.tgz

# copy init scripts to mariadb subchart
$ cp -a custom-init-scripts/. charts/mariadb/files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Now your init files are present in mariadb subchart

```
helm install --debug --dry-run --set mariadb.enabled=true .

...
---
# Source: mychart/charts/mariadb/templates/initialization-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: elevated-dragonfly-mariadb-master-init-scripts
  labels:
    app: mariadb
    component: "master"
    chart: mariadb-5.2.5
    release: "elevated-dragonfly"
    heritage: "Tiller"
binaryData:
data:
  init.sh: "echo \"hi\"\r\n"
  insert.sql: INSERT INT Users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: thank you, that works, i was hoping for a more elegant way :(

Comment: Is there a better way for this nowadays? Bitnami charts allow this to an extent (e.g. the [initDbScript] (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mysql#customize-a-new-mysql-instance) parameter), but it requires you to either embed the script content inside values.yaml or define another config-map yourself. It would be nice if the parent chart could pass some files to it's subcharts, no?